# How to write if else if condition in SQL | Oracle |

Tags: sql, oracle

I am little bit stuck need to write the SQL if else if  for below logic

As only basic knowledge on SQL

Below logic need to derived to SQL query

```
if depcost <> empcost and empcourseid in ('A','B') 
then

   empnfees=(empvar / empdar) * empcost

else if depcost <> empcost and empcourseid <> 'A'
then
     empnfees=empcost
else
     empnfees=depcost
```

Comment: Are these all columns in a table that you're querying?

Comment: @Mureinik : Yes all are their in table : employee

Answer (score 1):

Using a `CASE` expression, we can try:

```sql
CASE WHEN depcost <> empcost AND empcourseid IN ('A', 'B')
     THEN (empvar / empdar) * empcost
     WHEN depcost <> empcost AND empcourseid <> 'A'
     THEN empcost
     ELSE depcost END AS empnfees
```

Comment: Thanks tim let me try it

Answer (score 1):

If you can have `NULL` values then (as `NULL <> something` is never true):

```
CASE
WHEN (  depcost <> empcost
     OR (depcost IS NULL AND empcost IS NOT NULL)
     OR (depcost IS NOT NULL AND empcost IS NULL)
     )
AND  empcourseid in ('A','B')
THEN empvar / empdar * empcost
WHEN (  depcost <> empcost
     OR (depcost IS NULL AND empcost IS NOT NULL)
     OR (depcost IS NOT NULL AND empcost IS NULL)
     )
AND  (  empcourseid <> 'A'
     OR empcourseid IS NULL
     )
THEN empcost
ELSE depcost
END AS empnfees
```